# transient DNS issues with certain sites in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, dns

I'm having a rather bizarre DNS issue with Snow Leopard.

Certain sites - MSNBC.com being the most noticeable for me - have an odd issue with DNS, in all browsers. After not visiting the site after a while (30 minutes or so), the first attempt to access MSNBC.com results in a DNS error. Refreshing 1-5 times resolves the issue until the next ~30 minute period of inactivity.

Seen this on three separate Macs at this point. One from-the-factory Snow Leopard install, two upgrades. Most sites are just fine. I Google and found other reports of the same thing with MSNBC, but no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with their servers' configuration, or your ISPs. You have no control over either, unfortunately, but you can switch to Google's or OpenDNS's and see if they fare any better.

Comment: I'm using Google's DNS. If it were a problem with the servers or ISPs, why would it only show up in Snow Leopard?